# How to avoid computed-column duplicate computation in an SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have the following query:

```
Use Northwind 

select OrderID as 'Order ID', (UnitPrice * Quantity) as 'Total', case
when (UnitPrice * Quantity) > 100 then 'Good' else 'Bad'
end as 'Rating' from [Order Details]
```

Theoretically, it computes `(UnitPrice * Quantity)` two times, and I believe that this is a bad choice for the performance.

How to accomplish this (avoiding the duplicate computation) in an elegant way?

Comment: create a computed column in the table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE [Order Details]
     (..., UnitPrice INT, Quantity INT, Total AS UnitPrice * Quantity PERSISTED);


SELECT 
    OrderID AS 'Order ID',
    Total,
    CASE
       WHEN Total > 100 THEN 'Good'
       ELSE 'Bad'
    END AS 'Rating'
FROM [Order Details];
```